# Display Sales Pipe funnel chart windows 8 app using C#

Tags: windows-8, crm

I want to create a sales pipeline funnel chart, and display it to user. Is there any way to achieve this using CRM sdk using C# or any alternative?

Rohit

Comment: But you already use CRM Dynamics 2011?

Comment: I want to do it with crm SDK using C#.

Sorry I did not mentioned it on before, now corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use CRM SDK to show the funnel chart in another application. For that you have to use another chart API, and get the data from CRM, with CRM SDK. Take a look in [this](http://www.highcharts.com/) chart api.